# É possível pegar um título de uma imagem utilizando "GetElementsByTagName"?

Tags: javascript, imagem, slide

Se sim, como? Se não, tem algum modo que faça eu pegar o valor do title, para depois imprimir?
Por enquanto está assim(Dentro de uma função. Na imagem tem um onClick chamando a mesma).

```
var imagens = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        document.getElementById('legenda').innerHTML = imagens;
```

já tentei por um getAttribute também e nada

Answer (score 2):

Isto aqui mostra o title de todas as imagens da página:

```
var imagens = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i=0; i<imagens.length; i++) {
    alert(imagens[i].title)
}
```

---

Considerando o código que você incluiu na pergunta, talvez seja isto que você quer:

```
var imagens = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
// Joga A PRIMEIRA imagem encontrada na página para dentro da legenda
document.getElementById('legenda').appendChild(imagens[0]);
```

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo! É que eu estou tentando fazer que quando uma imagem for clicada, o titulo dela seja imprimido em uma id estava tentando fazer com um getElementById mas a minha dúvida era o que por no resultado... tentei mais ou menos com o que você disse e não obtive resultado, chegou até dar "undefined". Pode me dizer como eu vou poder estar fazendo isso?

Obrigado!

Comment: Pode [editar sua pergunta](/posts/65922/edit) e incluir o código que você já tem? Está difícil visualizar só com o que você disse.

Comment: Pronto, editei!

Comment: @Naldson Ainda não está muito claro o que você está tentando fazer, mas editei a resposta com base no seu código.

Comment: É quase isso. Mas com esse modo que você me disse ele imprime a imagem que eu cliquei.. Eu queria imprimir o titulo dela.

Comment: `document.getElementById('legenda').innerHTML = imagens[0].title;`